# Quorum Constellation TLS Trust Mode revoking a certificate

Tags: quorum, constellation

I have multiple quorum nodes setup. How does revoke a certificate for a node? Assuming the node has gone rogue, there is a need to revoke a certificate for the node

Answer (score 0):

with whitelist trust mode, you should be able to revoke the certificate simply by removing the entry in known host file (tlsknownclient or tlsknownserver).
If using CA trust mode, technique such as using a CRLs (Certificate Revocation List) can be used to deny access to certificates that are no longer trusted.